# using lftp or rsync on zlinux

Tags: linux, redhat, rsync, mainframe, lftp

quick question - can [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) or [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/FAQ.html) be used on z/linux for file mirroring with subfolders, and if so what are the limitations? Which would you recommend?

If not, what are some alternatives? I need to keep two folder-structures mirrored across sites (i.e. a two-way sync), by scripting (or configuring) something to either automatically check for changes and update, or do it regularly with a cron job.

note: I wanted to tag this "zlinux" but it doesn't exist and I don't have the rep to create it

Comment: If you have to choice, install `rsync`. It simply cannot be beat. Highly efficient, provides incremental sync, rather than a re-copy of the entire set of files (allowing you to mirror large data stores over relatively slow network links -- after the first full mirror), provides DRY_RUN test capability, fully configurable file times, permission and ownership control, etc..The comparison with `lftp` isn't even close...

Comment: OK That's helpful. Can they both be installed on z/linux?

Comment: I know of know reason why they couldn't be. If there isn't already a pre-built package for your distro, then the source is available for both and you can build and install yourself. I run Archlinux & SuSE, and it is standard on both.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 which distro are you unsing on your mainframe ? there's not only one, so it's hard to give a proper advice (flagging as off-topic, sounds more on-topic for serverfault)

Comment: yes, I thought it might be more serverfault - but the mirroring part of the question can be scripted so I wasn't sure. We're using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lftp and rsync can't be used for strict two-way mirroring, as this involves keeping a history between syncs. They can, however, be used for one-way mirroring; and have many options to do so.

They can both be installed and run on z/linux (at least, redhat enterprise 6.2).

If sftp/ssh is an option, use rsync as it is quicker (due to only sending parts of files, if that's all that's required). rsync requires a daemon to be running if the password is to be sent with a passwordfile (as opposed to using ssh keys or typing it each time); so that is a limitation of rsync.

lftp can have the password scripted; and can also use ssh (sftp) although it is more complicated to do so.

lftp is recursive by default (but can be made not to be); rsync needs to be told to act recursively

Answer (score 2):

FTP sends many headers to assemble the files, besides the data. Rsync works super faster because it just sends 1 special character to indicate the end of a file, and many more useful features. Rsync hands down :-)

Comment: OK That's helpful. Can they both be installed on z/linux?

Comment: Not sure about lftp, but rsync gets mentioned in z/Linux IBM redbooks so it seems possible.